# Html/Css Transparent iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Here is my problem, this green background in chat: [image]

Css:

```
html {
    background: transparent!important;
}
```

iFrame:

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" marginheight="0" style="height: 100%;margin-left: -19px;width: 520px;" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="/chatbox/index.forum?page=front&"></iframe>
```

How to be transparent in the right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `body` tag instead of `html` tag and out a space between `transparent` and `!important`

```
body {
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe 
{
    opacity: 0.4 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

your css, or you can place it `in-line`